# MYSQL, Calculating Patient hospital readmissions 28 Days

Tags: mysql

I'm am having difficulty in trying to make this work. I have the following table that has patients stay in a hospital. They each have an admission date and a discharge date, each stay has an episode id. For the life of me, I can not figure out how to query the table to work out if the patient has been discharged and been readmitted within 28 days of the previous stay. Any pointers would be appreciated.

| ID | Admission | Discharge | EpisodeID | PatientID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020-02-17 | 2020-03-10 | 1234 | 1 |
| 02 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-03-15 | 1235 | 2 |
| 03 | 2020-02-20 | 2020-03-19 | 1236 | 3 |
| 04 | 2020-03-17 | 2020-03-30 | 1237 | 1 |
| 05 | 2020-03-19 | 2020-03-25 | 1238 | 4 |
| 06 | 2020-03-22 | 2020-03-29 | 1239 | 5 |
| 07 | 2020-03-29 | 2020-04-03 | 1240 | 6 |
| 08 | 2020-03-30 | 2020-04-10 | 1241 | 2 |
| 09 | 2020-04-01 |  | 1242 | 7 |
| 10 | 2020-04-17 |  | 1243 | 2 |

Output

| ID | Admission | Discharge | EpisodeID | PatientID | Readmit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020-02-17 | 2020-03-10 | 1234 | 1 | N |
| 02 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-03-15 | 1235 | 2 | N |
| 03 | 2020-02-20 | 2020-03-19 | 1236 | 3 | N |
| 04 | 2020-03-17 | 2020-03-30 | 1237 | 1 | Y |
| 05 | 2020-03-19 | 2020-03-25 | 1238 | 4 | N |
| 06 | 2020-03-22 | 2020-03-29 | 1239 | 5 | N |
| 07 | 2020-03-29 | 2020-04-03 | 1240 | 6 | N |
| 08 | 2020-03-30 | 2020-04-10 | 1241 | 2 | Y |
| 09 | 2020-04-01 |  | 1242 | 7 | N |
| 10 | 2020-04-17 |  | 1243 | 2 | Y |

Comment: And, what did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: Use EXISTS over another copy of your table.

Comment: @luuk yeah I’ll own that. To be honest I tried creating a second table as a copy an joining them but it was a crap solution. Hence why I’m stuck.

Comment: @Akina thanks for that. I will investigate how to use it. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Slava I was able to get what I needed. If anyone else comes across this, here is the solution that I used; (If I have made any mistakes I apologize)

```
CREATE TABLE p (ID int, Admission date, Discharge date, EpisodeID int,  PatientID int);

INSERT INTO p VALUES
('01', '2020-02-17', '2020-03-10', 1234, 1),
('02', '2020-02-18', '2020-03-15', 1235, 2),
('03', '2020-02-20', '2020-03-19', 1236, 3),
('04', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-30', 1237, 1),
('05', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-25', 1238, 4),
('06', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-29', 1239, 5),
('07', '2020-03-29', '2020-04-03', 1240, 6),
('08', '2020-03-30', '2020-04-10', 1241, 2),
('09', '2020-04-01', null, 1242, 7),
('10', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-18', 1243, 2),
('11', '2020-04-17', null, 1244, 2);
```

```
SELECT 
  p.*,
  IF(DATEDIFF(p.Admission, prev.Discharge)<29,'Y','N') Readmit,
  DATEDIFF(p.Admission, prev.Discharge) Days_Between
FROM p
LEFT JOIN p prev ON p.PatientID = prev.PatientID 
    AND DATEDIFF(p.Admission, prev.Discharge) BETWEEN 1 AND 28 ;
```

```
+====+============+============+===========+===========+=========+==============+
| ID | Admission  | Discharge  | EpisodeID | PatientID | Readmit | Days_Between |
+====+============+============+===========+===========+=========+==============+
| 1  | 2020-02-17 | 2020-03-10 | 1234      | 1         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 2  | 2020-02-18 | 2020-03-15 | 1235      | 2         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 3  | 2020-02-20 | 2020-03-19 | 1236      | 3         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 4  | 2020-03-17 | 2020-03-30 | 1237      | 1         | Y       | 20           |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 5  | 2020-03-19 | 2020-03-25 | 1238      | 4         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 6  | 2020-03-22 | 2020-03-29 | 1239      | 5         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 7  | 2020-03-29 | 2020-04-03 | 1240      | 6         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 8  | 2020-03-30 | 2020-04-10 | 1241      | 2         | Y       | 26           |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 9  | 2020-04-01 | (null)     | 1242      | 7         | N       | (null)       |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 10 | 2020-04-17 | 2020-04-18 | 1243      | 2         | Y       | 8            |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 11 | 2020-04-17 | (null)     | 1244      | 2         | N       | 382          |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

[SQLize](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2ffac7d4513e08bd6322a3e22e29e6c6&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2ffac7d4513e08bd6322a3e22e29e6c6&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple LEFT JOIN in this case:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    IF(prev.PatientID IS NOT NULL, 'Y', 'N') Readmit
FROM p
LEFT JOIN p prev ON 
    p.PatientID = prev.PatientID AND 
    DATEDIFF(p.Admission, prev.Discharge) BETWEEN 1 AND 28 ;
```

Look [MySQL online fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=ced465545ab6003cfef49538bf4db220&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)